# Push randomed objects on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to random objects on array to "make a battle". The random works perfect, but sometimes repeat objects. Also, I can see my var ARR it's full of undefined. I don't understand how I need to do to random perfectly without repeated object and fill with randomed objects.

```
var avenger = [
        {id: 1, fullName: "Steve Rogers", avengerName: "Captain America", gender: "Male", city: "New York City", markAv: 10},
        {id: 2, fullName: "Tony Stark", avengerName: "IronMan", gender: "Male", city: "New York City", markAv: 15},
        {id: 3, fullName: "Thor Odinson", avengerName: "Thor", gender: "Male", city: "Los Angeles", markAv: 13},
        {id: 4, fullName: "Bruce Banner", avengerName: "Hulk", gender: "Male", city: "Maryland", markAv: 20},
        {id: 5, fullName: "Clint Barton", avengerName: "Hawkeye", gender: "Male", city: "Los Angeles", markAv: 8},
        {id: 6, fullName: "Natasha Romanoff", avengerName: "Black Widow", gender: "Female", city: "Paris", markAv: 14},
        {id: 7, fullName: "Nick Fury", avengerName: "Nick Fury", gender: "Female", city: "New York City", markAv: 5},
        {id: 8, fullName: "Jaume Serradell", avengerName: "Jaumeserr", gender: "Male", city: "Barcelona", markAv: 18}
    ]

    function avengerPairs(myObject) {

        var arr = [];

        for (var i=0; i<avenger.length; i++) {

            var randomAvenger = avenger[Math.floor(Math.random() * avenger.length)];

            if (randomAvenger[i] !== avenger[i]) {
                arr.push([randomAvenger, avenger[i+1]]);
                i++;    
            }
        }

        console.log(arr);

        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            console.log(Math.max(arr[i][0].markAv, arr[i][1].markAv));

            if (arr[i][0].markAv < arr[i][1].markAv) {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => " + arr[i][1].fullName + " is better!");
            } else if (arr[i][0].markAv === arr[i][1].markAv) {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => Are equals!");
            } else {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => " + arr[i][0].fullName + " is better!");
            }
        }
    }

avengerPairs(avenger);
```

Comment: Hi there -- are you trying to push random `avenger` _properties_ into the `arr` array or full `avenger` _objects_. (_example property_: `fullName: "Tony Stark"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe the problem is at `arr.push([random[i], random[i+1]])`.

If you look at the `console.log(random)` output, you'll realize that `random` represents an Object of a single avenger (i.e. `{ id: 4, fullName: 'Bruce Banner', avengerName: 'Hulk', gender: 'Male', city: 'Maryland',markAv: 20 }`).

That means `random[i]` and `random[i+1]` are both undefined.

My suggestion is to do `arr.push([random, avenger[i+1]]);`.

You could also use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove each avenger as you pair them up, so there are no duplicates.

Okay a few hours later and I went ahead and got it to work with splicing / without repeats. I left in a bunch of commented out console.log statements if you want to follow along.

```js
var avenger = [
        {id: 1, fullName: "Steve Rogers", avengerName: "Captain America", gender: "Male", city: "New York City", markAv: 10},
        {id: 2, fullName: "Tony Stark", avengerName: "IronMan", gender: "Male", city: "New York City", markAv: 15},
        {id: 3, fullName: "Thor Odinson", avengerName: "Thor", gender: "Male", city: "Los Angeles", markAv: 13},
        {id: 4, fullName: "Bruce Banner", avengerName: "Hulk", gender: "Male", city: "Maryland", markAv: 20},
        {id: 5, fullName: "Clint Barton", avengerName: "Hawkeye", gender: "Male", city: "Los Angeles", markAv: 8},
        {id: 6, fullName: "Natasha Romanoff", avengerName: "Black Widow", gender: "Female", city: "Paris", markAv: 14},
        {id: 7, fullName: "Nick Fury", avengerName: "Nick Fury", gender: "Female", city: "New York City", markAv: 5},
        {id: 8, fullName: "Jaume Serradell", avengerName: "Jaumeserr", gender: "Male", city: "Barcelona", markAv: 18}
    ]

    function avengerPairs(myObject) {

        var arr = [];
        var lengthSave = avenger.length

        for (var i=0; i<lengthSave; i++) {
            var newLength = avenger.length
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * newLength)
            var randomAvenger = avenger[index];
            var pairArr = (avenger.splice(index, 2)) 

            // console.log(avenger.length)
            // console.log(pairArr.length)

            if (pairArr.length < 2 ) {
                var anotherPair
                if (avenger.length > 1) {
                    anotherPair = avenger.splice(index, 1)[0]
                } else if (avenger.length === 1) {
                   anotherPair = avenger.splice(0, 1)[0]
                } 
                // console.log(!!anotherPair)
                // console.log(anotherPair)
                // console.log('another pair')

                if (!!anotherPair === true) {
                    pairArr.push(anotherPair)
                }
            }

            // console.log(pairArr)
            // console.log(!!pairArr[0])
            // console.log(!!pairArr[1])

            // console.log('pairArr')

            if (!!pairArr[0] === true && !!pairArr[1]) {
                arr.push(pairArr)   
            }


        }

        // console.log(arr);

        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            // console.log(Math.max(arr[i][0].markAv, arr[i][1].markAv));

            if (arr[i][0].markAv < arr[i][1].markAv) {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => " + arr[i][1].fullName + " is better!");
            } else if (arr[i][0].markAv === arr[i][1].markAv) {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => Are equals!");
            } else {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => " + arr[i][0].fullName + " is better!");
            }
        }
    }

avengerPairs(avenger);
```

Comment: Thanks @LShapz, I will try to find the solution. I don't understand some things but surely finally I will do!

Comment: Hello @LShapz. I tried your code and works perfectly but now I can't make the random without repeated objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your array is being filled with `undefined` because of these lines:

```
var arr = [];

for (var i=0; i<avenger.length; i++) {

    var random = avenger[Math.floor(Math.random() * avenger.length)];

    console.log(random);
    arr.push([random[i], random[i+1]]);
    i++;
}
```

`random` successfully creates a random index to look into the `avenger` array and assigns the corresponding value in the array to the variable `random`.

You should see this successfully in the following `console.log`.

It's the next line that gives you trouble.  Inside your push call, you try to access two indices on the `random` variable with `random[i]` and `random[i + 1]`.  This returns undefined, because your `random` variable is not an array of avengers but **a single avenger**, and the integer keys don't exist on that object, thus returning `undefined`.

I would recommend a better name for your `random` variable.  Perhaps `randomAvenger`?  That would help make it clear that you're incorrectly indexing into an avenger, instead of an array of avengers.

To successfully pair two avengers, you will need two separate random indexes into the `avengers` array.  You'll also want to watch out for selecting the same avenger twice though!

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I will try to figure it.

Comment: I tried to fix that. Now it's perfect. Random works perfectly, but I can't do the random without repeated objects on the array @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Random works perfectly, but I can't random avenger with randomAvenger to prevent repeated values. Now, between two values into objects in array [a,b] [a,b] it's perfect, but between values to objects, continues repeating values.

That's my code new code:

```
var avenger = [
        {id: 1, fullName: "Steve Rogers", avengerName: "Captain America", gender: "Male", city: "New York City", markAv: 10},
        {id: 2, fullName: "Tony Stark", avengerName: "IronMan", gender: "Male", city: "New York City", markAv: 15},
        {id: 3, fullName: "Thor Odinson", avengerName: "Thor", gender: "Male", city: "Los Angeles", markAv: 13},
        {id: 4, fullName: "Bruce Banner", avengerName: "Hulk", gender: "Male", city: "Maryland", markAv: 20},
        {id: 5, fullName: "Clint Barton", avengerName: "Hawkeye", gender: "Male", city: "Los Angeles", markAv: 8},
        {id: 6, fullName: "Natasha Romanoff", avengerName: "Black Widow", gender: "Female", city: "Paris", markAv: 14},
        {id: 7, fullName: "Nick Fury", avengerName: "Nick Fury", gender: "Female", city: "New York City", markAv: 5},
        {id: 8, fullName: "Jaume Serradell", avengerName: "Jaumeserr", gender: "Male", city: "Barcelona", markAv: 18}
    ]

    function avengerPairs(myObject) {

        var arr = [];

        for (var i=0; i<avenger.length; i++) {

            var randomAvenger = avenger[Math.floor(Math.random() * avenger.length)];


            if (randomAvenger !== avenger[i]) {
                arr.push([randomAvenger, avenger[i+1]]);
                i++;    
            } else {
                console.log("Not equals");
            }   
        }

        console.log(arr);

        /*
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            console.log(Math.max(arr[i][0].markAv, arr[i][1].markAv));

            if (arr[i][0].markAv < arr[i][1].markAv) {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => " + arr[i][1].fullName + " is better!");
            } else if (arr[i][0].markAv === arr[i][1].markAv) {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => Are equals!");
            } else {
                console.log(arr[i][0].fullName + " vs " + arr[i][1].fullName + " => " + arr[i][0].fullName + " is better!");
            }
        }
        */
    }

avengerPairs(avenger);
```

Comment: hey jaumeserr, I added a revised version using splicing to deal with duplication to my comment above. if it works for you, maybe mark the answer as correct?

Comment: @LSharpz Works perfectly! Thank you very very much!